How does pygame assign indices to joysticks?
I have two identical Logitech joysticks, connected to the same computer. I am using pygame to interact with them. Pygame seems to assign indices randomly to the controllers. I want to know which physical joystick is related to which index each time, because I want to assign the physical joysticks to two different robots. How could I do that?
I have tried to go though all the devices using win32com.client, and I can identify which device is a joystick. then, I assumed that pygame assigns indices in the order that win finds them. But that assumption was wrong. Here is a snippet of my code.
joystick_identifiers = {
    "Logitech_F710": {
        "vid": "046D",
        "pid": "C21F",
    },
}


def find_devices() -> list[dict]:
    """
    Find all connected joysticks and return their information as a list of dictionaries.

    Returns
    -------
    found_joysticks: list[dict]
        A list of dictionaries containing joystick UID, name, index, VID, and PID.
    """
    found_joysticks = []
    wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")
    pygame.joystick.init()  # Initialize the joystick module

    # Initialize the joystick index to 0
    jid = 0

    # Iterate through all the joysticks in the identifiers and connect them to a device
    for joystick_name, _ in joystick_identifiers.items():
        vid = joystick_identifiers[joystick_name]["vid"]
        pid = joystick_identifiers[joystick_name]["pid"]
        for device in wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_PnPEntity"):
            match = re.search(r"VID_([0-9A-F]+)&PID_([0-9A-F]+)\\([0-9A-F]+)", device.DeviceID, re.IGNORECASE)
            if match:
                port_vid, port_pid, port_uid = match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3)
                if port_vid == vid and port_pid == pid:
                    found_joysticks.append(
                        {
                            "joystick_uid": port_uid,
                            "device_name": joystick_name,
                            "vid": port_vid,
                            "pid": port_pid,
                            "joystick_index": jid,
                            "device_address": device.DeviceID,
                        }
                    )
                    jid += 1
    return found_joysticks

I thought that jid would be the index given using self.joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(jid) and I could somehow connect them, but it seems that it is random. Is there any way to achieve that, using pygame or any other library?
